# how do i evaluate a cfif with a select statement in a string

Tags: sql, database, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfml

```
sel_prod_dt = "select distinct change_app_code, change_number "
          & " \<cfif NDA_check eq "
          &'"Y"' 
          &"> FROM db.tb tb"
          &"\<cfelse\>FROM db.tb2 PC\<\/cfif\>"
```

i get the following error

**Syntax error, expected something like a name or a Unicode delimited identifier between the word 'change_number' and the end of the request.**

could anyone please help me in this regard..

Comment: Do you want to use if condition on database or on ColdFusion variable?

Comment: For future reference, the above is not valid cfml/cfscript code. When possible, you should post a [*self-contained* repro case](http://www.sscce.org/). Also, always include your dbms type with SQL questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why over complicate things?

```
<cfif NDA_check eq "Y">
    sel_prod_dt = "select distinct change_app_code, change_number FROM db.tb tb"
<cfelse>
    sel_prod_dt = "select distinct change_app_code, change_number FROM db.tb2 PC"
</cfif>
```

Comment: It might be that NDA_check is column name in the db. I am not sure though.

Comment: Anyone else reading this: Because `<cfqueryparam>` MUST be nested within a cfquery, you should not assemble queries as strings. It simply is not the proper way to do things. While it's almost harmless in a query that contains no variables, there's still small risk and no gain. No offense to Ocssor.

Comment: No problem, it's sage advice.

Comment: @cfqueryparam that's only a correct observation if using `<cfquery>`. If using Query.cfc or `queryExecute()` one can place one's parameter placeholders directly in the SQL string.

Comment: @AdamCameron Absolutely true. And I do wish tag-params had the equivalent flexibility, because it is a great aspect. For the tags however, building an sql string is not worth the loss of cfqueryparam.

Comment: @cfqueryparam: go vote for this one then: https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3732993.

Answer (score 6):

One cannot add CFML to a string and them somehow expect it to run! Strings aren't processed until runtime, and the CFML code needs to be compiled before it'll run.

Reading this should clarify "[The ColdFusion request/response process](http://blog.adamcameron.me/2012/10/the-coldfusion-requestresponse-process.html)"

So you need to have complete and syntactically correct CFML in your file *before* it runs.

You have not given enough detail in your question to be able to help with the actual code solution for your issue, but basically @Ocssor has probably got it right.

Comment: That looks like a db error message. So it is possible the actual code *does* compile. However, even if it did, cfml code runs on the CF server, not in the database. So it makes no sense to embed cfml code *within* a SQL string. That may be what is causing the db error. However, without more details, that is just a guess. As Adam said, you need to provide more information.

Comment: @Leigh Oh, it's def from the DB as the string isn't valid SQL. Because the OP is expecting the CFML to *execute*, not to remain in the string.

Comment: Duh, I just realized I misread the first part of your comment and that is what you were saying already. I need more caffeine ;-)

Comment: I really hate this kind of SQL. It takes away CF's nice clean way of working with DB code - one of it's clear assets.

Answer (score 2):

Assembling an sql query dynamically (into a string) is often dangerous and rarely necessary (and when it is, it's time to reconsider things, and consider again if you still think it is). It also sacrifices the ability to use a critically important tag, cfqueryparam.

So, you'd do something like this

```
<cfquery...>
  select distinct change_app_code, change_number
    <cfif NDA_check eq '"Y"'>FROM db.tb tb
    <cfelse>FROM db.tb2 PC</cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Now here's a great time to use Ternary Ifs, they look a lot cleaner

(Is the value of NDA check really supposed to be `"Y"` I couldn't tell, more likely, it's supposed to be `Y`. You may need to change that.)

```
<cfquery...>
  select distinct change_app_code, change_number
    FROM #(NDA_check eq '"Y"' ? "db.tb tb" : "db.tb2 PC")#
</cfquery>
```

Ternary IFs can be used in strings like you're trying to do:

```
<cfset myfavcolor = "green">
<cfset yourfavcolor "red">
<cfset DoWeAgree = "We have #(myfavcolor is yourfavcolor ? "the same favorite color" : "different favorite colors")#">
```

However, they operate on a very simple If / else nature. The only way to else if is to nest another Ternary if, so they're really not ideal for elseifs, especially many elseifs.

```
<cfset myfavcolor = "green">
<cfset yourfavcolor "red">
<cfset DoWeAgree = "We have #(myfavcolor is yourfavcolor ? "the same favorite color" : (yourfavcolor is not "purple" ? "different favorite colors" : "... I'm not talking to you, you like purple"))#">
```

For the record, it seems strange to me that you're not taking advantage of table aliasing. Using my cfquery sample from above.

```
<cfquery...>
  select distinct change_app_code, change_number
    FROM #(NDA_check eq '"Y"' ? "db.tb" : "db.tb2")# theTB
</cfquery>
```

That way, whichever table it pulls from, you can reference the table (within the query) as theTB.

---

Now, for some advice.

If you ever feel the need to load a table name into a variable name

```
select * from #thetable#
```

Make sure to scope that variable. If it's something you set in the page, set it like this

```
<cfset variables.thetable = "mytable">
```

and

```
select * from #variables.thetable#
```

But, as a rule, I stay away from dropping a variable into a query if I can't `<cfqueryparam>` and table names can't be `<cfqueryparam>`'d.

If i absolutely must, I scope that variable, as I demonstrated, so that I know the source, because...

```
select * from #thetable#
```

Could accidentally end up with a source of url.thetable or form.thetable which is disastrous and open to SQL Injection.

---

More advice, since you're just starting out with CF, you should start a good (and critically important) habit now `<cfqueryparam>` every #variable# in the where clause of your queries. It should also be used for every user-configurable variable in insert or update queries. It's always important to do this. (Unfortunately you can't cfqueryparam a dynamic table name).

Read up on cfqueryparam here: [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html)

The tag may look longwinded (and it is, I'll never know what adobe was thinking) but it's your first line of defense against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: This is all lovely, but it doesn't really address the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

To use conditional logic when building strings, do it one step at a time.

```
sqlString = "select field1, field2 ";
if (something) {
sqlString &= ", field3";
}
sqlString &= " rest of the query goes here";
```